# Non-class-name C++11 type-name that is a simple-template-id?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In the C++11 standard it describes `type-name` and `class-name` with the following grammars:

```
type-name:
    class-name
    enum-name
    typedef-name
    simple-template-id        <--- HERE

class-name:
    identifier
    simple-template-id
```

My question is about the `simple-template-id` that is the direct descendant of `type-name`.

Is it ever possible to have a `simple-template-id` that is a `type-name` but is not a `class-name`?

For example if `foo<bar>` names a type, can it ever be a non-class type?

(If the answer is no, is there some other reason I'm missing why `simple-template-id` is repeated under `type-name`?)

Comment: When you quote the standard, it's generally best to include the section number or the paragraph name (the `[something.something]` at the top-right of the section) so others can find what you're talking about, in case they need/want more context.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: There is an "Index of grammar productions" in the back of the standard which gives the page numbers of where a particular grammar is mentioned in the main text and also its location in the Annex A grammar summary - however I think the answer cannot be found locally to a particular section (or at least not locally to where these grammars are mentioned).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, for example:

```
template <typename T> using Ptr = T *;

Ptr<int> p = 0;
```

Comment: This is an "alias template", 14.5.7 [temp.alias].

Comment: This is new in C++11, and indeed C++03 does not include *simple-template-id* as a production rule for *type-name*, only for *class-name*.

Comment: It's interesting that `simple-template-id` was not added to `typedef-name` to cover this instead.  Perhaps there are semantics that apply to `typedef-names` that do not apply to alias templates.